# Change dd command in evil mode to not write to clipboard

Tags: emacs, clipboard, evil-mode

I would like to use normal modes commands like `d` `c` `x` etc without the content being copied to clipboard.

I want to make emacs so that only `y` command will write anything to the clipboard. Other commands like `d` should only delete the content without writing anything to the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [Gordon Gustafson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37803317/2724649) use `arround advice`. `evil-delete` is what used by emacs for all kinds of delete, so making that to delete to a blackhole register fixed the issue. Just add the following to your `.emacs`

```
(defun bb/evil-delete (orig-fn beg end &optional type _ &rest args)
    (apply orig-fn beg end type ?_ args))
(advice-add 'evil-delete :around 'bb/evil-delete)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a step in the right direction:

```
(evil-define-operator evil-change-into-null-register (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Change text from BEG to END with TYPE. Do not save it in any register."
  (interactive "<R><x><y>")
  (evil-change beg end type ?_ yank-handler))

(evil-define-operator evil-delete-into-null-register (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Delete text from BEG to END with TYPE. Do not save it in any register."
  (interactive "<R><x><y>")
  (evil-delete beg end type ?_ yank-handler))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map "c" 'evil-change-into-null-register)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "d" 'evil-delete-into-null-register)
```

However, `C`, `D`, `s`, `S`, `x`, `X`, and potentially several others would also need to be rebound, and this doesn't seem to work properly for `x` (it still expects a motion):

```
(evil-define-operator evil-delete-char-into-null-register (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Delete text from BEG to END with TYPE. Do not save it in any register."
  (interactive "<R><x>")
  (evil-delete-char beg end type ?_ yank-handler))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map "x" 'evil-delete-char-into-null-register)
```

Your best bet is add [around advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) around `evil-delete` and always pass it the `?_` register (sorry, I don't have time to do that now, but I thought I'd post what I had).

Answer (score 0):

This is not easily possible because the delete operator calls the yank operator. However, you could redefine `evil-delete` and simply remove the call to `evil-yank`.